# CSS Overflow: Scroll in wrong place?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I am in the middle of creating a website using Dreamweaver CC 2014. The Homepage scrolls fine, but the About page and Calendar page doesn't scroll at all and cuts off the bottom half that should be displaying. I've read the other threads that say to add the overflow: scroll code to the CSS. I have done that, but it still isn't working and I'm wondering if I have placed the code in the wrong place?

Here is the link to the Calendar page:
http://normajdougherty.com/Calendar.html

Would you look at the CSS and HTML code and let me know what the problem is? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
position:fixed;
```

Specified in your navigation bar, which is effectively "locking" the page in place. If you set its position to relative, your menu items (which should also not be set to "fixed") are no longer going to be attached to the navbar.

But the way you have implemented the navbar in the first place is kind of kludgy. You don't need a separate div for the blue bar in the background.

Instead of having two overlapping fixed divs, which is a bad practice for several reasons, just place your navigation buttons in a single div with a background color, using the "background-color" property.

Also, the reason it looks "cut off" halfway down is because that's just the size of the image you're using in the background. Consider setting up a color gradient or something, or honestly just leave the background a solid color. Unless you do something particularly fancy, a big static image like that is not going to look the way you want it to.

**EDIT**: Okay, at second glance, it looks like your entire page is wrapped within the navigation bar div. That's why the whole page is locked in place when "position:fixed" is set. Make sure you close the tag for the navbar before the rest of the page content starts.

But still, you shouldn't have a fixed navbar like that in the middle of the page, as it will scroll down with the rest of your content and just end up looking really bad.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set

```
 positon:fixed;
```

in navbar class.
remove it and page will work fine

So remove

```
position:fixed
```

from .navbar class in calendar.css

Answer (score 0):

You're facing this problem because the content part of your page is wrapped inside the `navbar` div which has been assigned a `fixed` position. You will need to add the `intro` div and the `<iframe>` after the `navbar` div for your website to function properly.

This is how that particular part of code currently looks like on your website (notice `<div class="intro">` and the `<iframe>` is inside `<div class="fluid navbar">`):

```
<div class="fluid navbar">
    <img src="images/BlueNavBar.png" alt="navigation menu">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT ME</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href: "books.html"="">BOOKS</a>
            </li>
            <li>BLOG</li>
            <li>MEDIA KIT</li>
            <li>SPEAKER</li>
            <li><a href="Calendar.html" calendar<="" a=""></a>
            </li><a href="Calendar.html" calendar<="" a="">
        <li>CONTACT</li></a>
        </ul><a href="Calendar.html" calendar<="" a="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="intro">
        <p><b>Below is a monthly calendar of the events I will be attending, participating in or speaking. <br>I may also post my blog schedule, contests and other giveaways.</b>
        </p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <center>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=sffk4qmbgj5b1e08d7lkg84rr0%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;ctz=America/New_York" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </center>
</div>
```

And this is how you should modify it (both `<div class="intro">` and the `<iframe>` are added after `<div class="fluid navbar">`):

```
<div class="fluid navbar">
    <img src="images/BlueNavBar.png" alt="navigation menu">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT ME</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href: "books.html"="">BOOKS</a>
            </li>
            <li>BLOG</li>
            <li>MEDIA KIT</li>
            <li>SPEAKER</li>
            <li><a href="Calendar.html" calendar<="" a=""></a>
            </li><a href="Calendar.html" calendar<="" a="">
        <li>CONTACT</li></a>
        </ul><a href="Calendar.html" calendar<="" a="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="intro">
    <p><b>Below is a monthly calendar of the events I will be attending, participating in or speaking. <br>I may also post my blog schedule, contests and other giveaways.</b>
    </p>
</div>
<br/>
<center><iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=sffk4qmbgj5b1e08d7lkg84rr0%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;ctz=America/New_York" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this two styles in at header section of Calendar.html (this code is writing as internal css, because this code don't affect other pages)

`#menu {position: absolute; }
.navbar {position: static;}`